# Arch Linux PowerPC installation guide for absolute beginners

Tags: arch-linux, powerpc

I was wondering if there was an Arch Linux installation guide for absolute beginners for PowerPC.  I've been using the one on the website, and I receive errors such as "the Linux kernel package could not be installed".  I think I'm not following the instructions correctly.

Comment: what distribution is it? Powerpc is no longer officially supported (since Ubuntu 6 or so...)

Comment: I didn't realize my question was off-topic, I'll ask it on unix.  Thanks, warriorIng64

Comment: By "one on the website" do you mean the Official Guide? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Official_Install_Guide_on_a_PowerPC

Comment: From the archlinuxppc.com website

Answer (score 1):

ppc on arch is not well supported (much less so than on Ubuntu).

If want to run a modern Linux on ppc, your best options are either Debian or Ubuntu. The best solution IMHO is the Debian kernel (so suspend works) and Ubuntu user land, just installing Ubuntu (which is simple from the CD/DVD image) will get you 98% there with little difficulty.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I've had problems choosing a right version in the past, what version should I pick?  I have 384mb of ram and a 300mhz processor.

Comment: Note that Debian has dropped support for PowerPC in 9 and Ubuntu in 17.04.